# Read specific key from redis using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, redis, spark-redis

I am trying to read a specific key from Redis using pyspark.
As per documentation, I haven't found any specific command to read a particular key. Using the below code I can read all data from Redis:

```
testid = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")\
.option("table",'testing123')\
.option("key.column","id")\
.load()
```

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `keys.pattern`. From the [docs](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/dataframe.md#reading-redis-hashes):

> To read Redis Hashes you have to provide a keys pattern with
> `.option("keys.pattern", keysPattern)` option. The DataFrame schema
> should be explicitly specified or can be inferred from a random row.
>
> [...] Spark-Redis tries to extract the key based on the key pattern:
>
> - if the pattern ends with `*` and it's the only wildcard, the trailing substring will be extracted
> - otherwise there is no extraction - the key is kept as is.

```
testid = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis") \
.option("keys.pattern", "keyPattern:*") \
.option("key.column","id") \
.option("infer.schema", "true") \
.load()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried this option but getting below error. Seems it is not taking table and key.pattern together

testid = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")\
.option("table",'testing123')\
.option("keys.pattern", "testing123:44038:1000") \
.option("key.column","id")\
.load()

error :-java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both options &#39;table&#39; and &#39;table&#39; are set. You should only use either one.

Comment: `table` is the implicit `keys.pattern`...  so you can use either one or another

Comment: it seems working with below command

`testid = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")\
.option("keys.pattern", "testing123:44038:1000") \
.option("infer.schema", "true") \
.load()
`


But format seems wrong, id column should come first but other column is coming.

+-----------------------+---------------------+
|1367366400_002222222222|_id|
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|1                      |                  testing123:44038:1000|
+-----------------------+---------------------+

Comment: @blackbishop , can we pass keyPattern:* values dynamically, using some variable?
lets say if x = cell:12345
then it should be like `.option("keys.pattern", "x") \`